# How to limit the use of a validation constraint (Captcha Assert) only for a specific action/context (registration and not update)

Tags: validation, symfony

My app uses Symfony 2.8 with symfony-captcha-bundle. My user entity has captcha validation during the registration process and it works as expected.
If after I make an update of the user object, app returns the error:

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception 
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Catchable Fatal Error: 
Argument 1 passed to Captcha\Bundle\CaptchaBundle\Helpers\BotDetectCaptchaHelper::__construct() must implement interface 
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface, null given, called in C:\apps\Apache24\htdocs\WodProject\vendor\captcha-com\symfony-captcha-bundle\Integration\BotDetectCaptcha.php
on line 68 and defined" at C:\apps\Apache24\htdocs\WodProject\vendor\captcha-com\symfony-captcha-bundle\Helpers\BotDetectCaptchaHelper.php 
line 26 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\ContextErrorException(code: 0): 
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Captcha\\Bundle\\CaptchaBundle\\Helpers\\BotDetectCaptchaHelper::__construct() 
must implement interface Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Session\\SessionInterface, null given, called in C:\\apps\\Apache24\\htdocs\\WodProject\\vendor\\captcha-com\\symfony-captcha-bundle\\Integration\\BotDetectCaptcha.php 
on line 68 and defined at C:\\apps\\Apache24\\htdocs\\WodProject\\vendor\\captcha-com\\symfony-captcha-bundle\\Helpers\\BotDetectCaptchaHelper.php:26)"} []
```

The Captcha validation into user entity:

```
/**
* @CaptchaAssert\ValidCaptcha(
* message = "registration.errorCatpcha"
* )
*/
protected $captchaCode;
```

I think that the problem is that the constraint is always triggered. I need to know how to activate the constraint only during the user registration and disable it on other actions (update, etc...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign a **Validation Group** to the constraint like the example below (using annotations):

```
/**
* @CaptchaAssert\ValidCaptcha(
*     message = "registration.errorCatpcha",
*     groups={"registration"} <--- VALIDATION GROUP
* )
*/
protected $captchaCode;
```

Depending by your needs you can add one or more validation groups to use a specific assert in different forms/contexts `groups={"registration", "edit", "other"}`

Then you can read the docs to see:

- [How to define the validation group in your forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/validation_groups.html)
- [How to define the validation group to validate an object directly (without using the form component)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html)